# Add a route/action to one of ActiveAdmin base controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a search collection action which I want to be accessible and overridable by all of my resource controllers in ActiveAdmin. It's trivial to create controller actions in a single Active Admin resource with the following code:

```
collection_action :autocomplete_user_last_name, method: :get

  def autocomplete_user
    term  = params[:term]
    users = User.where('first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%").order(:first_name)
    render json: users.map { |user|
      {
        id:            user.id,
        label:         user.full_name,
        value:         user.full_name
      }
    }
  end
```

But how would I create a similar action within the ActiveAdmin base controller? Within Rails, `ApplicationController` behaves just like any other controller where we can create routes, actions, helper methods, etc., however, I only want this action to be scoped to Active Admin, not my entire App. Is there an equivalent to ApplicationController in ActiveAdmin?

Looking through the AA code, I found the following base controllers which are the superclasses of all resource controllers:

```
ActiveAdmin::PageController
ActiveAdmin::BaseController
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController
```

However, the `collection` and `member` actions aren't defined within these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up scoping the route/controller action to a specific resource. Not sure if what I'm asking is currently possible with AA's API.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all AA resource controllers inherit from `ActiveAdmin::ResourceController'. See documentation here [Class: ActiveAdmin::ResourceController](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/ActiveAdmin/ResourceController)

I'm working from memory here, but I would start by wrapping your controller code in `active_admin.rb` with the following:

```
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do

  collection_action :autocomplete_user_last_name, method: :get do

    def autocomplete_user
      term  = params[:term]
      users = User.where('first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? OR email LIKE ?', "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%", "%#{term}%").order(:first_name)
      render json: users.map { |user|
        {
          id:            user.id,
          label:         user.full_name,
          value:         user.full_name
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. `collection_action` isn't defined in that context.

Comment: You're right. collection_action is defined in the AA DSL. I ran across this: https://www.viget.com/articles/8-insanely-useful-activeadmin-customizations  but haven't figured out how to mix collection_action into the module.

Comment: Thanks saw that. I just ended up scoping the route/controller action to a specific resource. Not sure if what I'm asking is currently possible with AA's API.